# INNER JOIN query performance very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, query-performance

I have a SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableB ta
INNER JOIN tableB tb ON tb.someColumn = ta.someOtherColumn
```

Both, `someColumn` and `someOtherColumn`, are *not* the primary key of their tables. Both are of the datatype `int`.

`TableA` has ~500.000 records, `tableB` has ~250.000 records. The query takes about 2 minutes to finish, which is much too long in my opinion.

The query execution plan looks as follows:

[image]

I already tried to (a) use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` and (b) create an `INDEX` on the respective tables. To no avail.

My question is: How can the performance of this query be improved?

Comment: How many rows are being produced?  What indexes did you create?

Comment: How many columns are you trying to return? SELECT * will be slow if you are trying to return too many columns

Comment: The record counts are not huge.  Are there large text/varchar columns ?

Comment: " (b) create an INDEX on the respective tables."  What indexes did you create?

Comment: How long it takes to dump this to a temp table? It might an issue of selecting all of these rows in management studio.

Comment: Post your DDL of your tables and the respective indexes of said tables. That query plan shows that both tables are being read via a scan, so any indexes you do have aren't being used for a seek; and hence one reason why this is slow.

Comment: @JNevill I created indexes on the columns that are used for the JOIN.

Comment: @beta and does that index include (`INCLUDE`) all the other columns (as you're using `SELECT *`)? Please actually post the definition of those indexes in your question; as your query plan clearly shows that you do *not* have a covering index. Do you have a `CLUSTERED INDEX` too..?

Comment: It seems to me that your query and execution plan look fine, that most of those 2 minutes are expend filling the grid on the Management Studio. Please, try select count(*) instead of select *. It's the same but instead of filling a grid it only returns the number of rows. Let's see how much time is used calculating data and how much time filling the grid on Management Studio.

Comment: Also seem like the issue is on `JOIN` not the `INDEX` scan. Maybe you don't have many different values on `someColumn`. If you have 500k records but only values 1,2,3 and the same for tableB  you may end with 1B rows. Try `COUNT(*)`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza and @MarcGuillot, you are right. With `COUNT(*)` the query executes really quick. That's interesting.

Comment: How much rows you got from `COUNT(*)` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I get 400k rows.

Comment: How many fields would you get for * both tables?

Comment: The index use could be quite different for `COUNT(*)` though, @JuanCarlosOropeza . As `SELECT *` will need to get all the values from the columns; which could/will require a different index (and won't have one if there are no covering indexes).

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza ~25 fields.

Comment: I think is time you post the DDL. You have some great guys here already willing to help but we only can guess with what you give us. There is no reason for a query bringing 400k take 2 min. Unless you have a very slow disk

Comment: query plan for `COUNT(*)` see here: https://imgur.com/a/uf3Pbgs

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on tb.SomeColumn, and create another index on ta.SomeOtherColumn.

Then when you run this query, the Hash Match should be replaced with an Inner Loop, and will be much faster.

Comment: See what happen when you dont provide the DDL. We waste time guessing :(

Comment: @beta you probably implemented something incorrectly.  I can't help you further unless you provide a script that reproduces the issue.